# something similar to this without using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, events

The script below is pretty basic I guess, it starts loading something "on blur".

```
<script>
window.onblur = function(){
  TIMER = setTimeout(changeItUp, 5000);
}  

window.onfocus = function(){
  if(TIMER) clearTimeout(TIMER);
}

function changeItUp()
{
  location.href = "http://www.yahoo.com"
}
</script>
```

So, if I want to redirect the user to something else after a certain period of inactivity, is there any chance to do this without using Javascript?

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: No

Long answer: The only way to detect user activities on a page is via Javascript. No javascript, no keyup/keydown/focus/blur events to trigger on. You could do a redirect after 5 seconds using a `<meta>` tag redirect, but that's an unconditional redirect. No matter what the user is doing on the page, it'd still redirect after the specified time is elapsed.

Comment: some browsers process even the meta redirect with their javascript engine, so no javascript, no meta direct on those as well.

Comment: Which browsers? Meta redirect was around long before javascript crawled onto the scene.

Comment: Opera mobile for sure (verified). Opera 10 desktop had similar functionality till Opera 11. I'd have to dig up my notes on it to remember all the instances, but I remember running across the issue on a project not too long ago.  I'm sure you know by now, just because the W3C spec tells browsers they should do something one way doesn't mean they listen.

Comment: Meta redirects couldn't have been around *long before* JavaScript. The Web (as we know it) appeared in 1993, and JavaScript in 1995. I don't know which browser introduced meta redirects, but it was probably around 1995.

Comment: @colinross, i believe you are mistaking about desktop Opera, they have distinct option to disobey non-standard `Refresh`

Answer (score 1):

No. HTML alone does not have the ability to redirect users as a certain time period has elapsed (conditionally). You will have to use javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Meta Refresh will do something similar but only after a period of time regardless of activity...

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5;url=http://yahoo.com/">
```

Otherwise, like others stated, only JavaScript.

Comment: he have said, when the user is inactiv.

Comment: @Vural Acar... yes, just like I said, _"but only after a period of time **regardless of activity**"_